# SQL default row values

Tags: postgresql

If I have a table containing some data such as:

| ID | some_field1 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | this is a default row with default configuration |
| 1 | user configured this field |

Would `SELECT whatever FROM table WHERE id=? OR id=0 LIMIT 1;` always return the configured row first unless it doesn't exist?

Additionally is there a way that could check if some_field1 is configured independently of other fields without writing all the default values? Say id1 has some_field1 as null but some_field2 configured to something custom, this query would return null instead of the default unless I use the DEFAULT VALUE in the schema creation (and keep that up to date with the row in the database).

I know it could be implemented in the program logic fairly easily but I was wondering if there is a one query solution in SQL itself.

Comment: You need `ORDER BY` to get the rows of a table in a certain order. Every other order is a coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

If ? is null this query return whatever entity id = 0 otherwise it return entity id =?

```
SELECT whatever FROM table WHERE id= coalesce(?,0) LIMIT 1;
```